# how to make request with client-side certification and certification key in Swift

Tags: swift, urlsession

I would like to convert following `request.get` statement from python to swift. However under python, I can pass cert with tuple type of value. how can I convert the same code in swift?

```
import requests
cert_file_path = "cert.pem"
key_file_path = "key.pem"

url = "https://example.com/resource"
params = {"param_1": "value_1", "param_2": "value_2"}
cert = (cert_file_path, key_file_path)
r = requests.get(url, params=params, cert=cert)
```

I have tried

```
import UIKit

let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/resource")!

let certPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "certification.pem")
let certification = try? String(contentsOf: certPath)
let certKeyPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "certification.key.pem")
let certKey = try? String(contentsOf: certKeyPath)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let data = data {
        if let books = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Book].self, from: data) {
            print(books)
        } else {
            print("Invalid Response")
        }
    } else if let error = error {
        print("HTTP Request Failed \(error)")
    }
}
```

of course, I can't get any data from response. so how can I pass client-side certification and certification key along with URLSession or there is different way to make request in swift?

Comment: Use the delegate on `URLSession`, namely the [urlSession(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondelegate/1409308-urlsession).

Comment: can you provide some example how to use?